# How to suppress lombok warnings

Tags: java, lombok, java-annotations

I have an Entity

```
@Builder
class MyEntity {
   private Set<OtherEntitiy> children = new HashSet<>()
}
```

And i get a lombok warning.

> warning: @Builder will ignore the initializing expression entirely. If you want the initializing expression to serve as default, add @Builder.Default. If it is not supposed to be settable during building, make the field final.
>       Set = new HashSet<>();

The question is: how can i suppress lombok's warning?

Also. I need to initialize children because i want to avoid NullPointerException. Also i can't mark this filed as final because it is not final really. I cant mark filed `@Builder.Default` because i wanna create this entity not only with builder and i wanna to save default value for other constructors.

Comment: I think Lombok is trying to tell you that it always overwrites that value. https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/916 I don't really know Lombok very well but a workaround could be to target a constructor with `@Builder` instead of the class.

Comment: I think the warning is pretty self explanatory and you should think of fixing the warning by following the suggestions in the message instead of trying to suppress it.

Comment: @dpr you are right. First we need think how to fix the issue. But in this case suggested decision is not acceptable. I had explain it in my question above.

Comment: Just some ideas: 1. You could add `@AllArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)` and remove the initialization. The Builder will do the initialization and you wan't call you private ctor. +++ 2. You maybe could use `@Singular`. +++ 3. The field should probably be final as you can do everything by modifying the collection instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Use `@Builder.Default`to add default behavior for your `Builder`

```
@Builder
class MyEntity {
   @Builder.Default
   private Set<String> children = new HashSet<>();
}
```

You use it on the field that has a default value defined an `Lombok`
 will then pick up the value during object creation
[`@Builder.Default`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) functionality was added in `lombok v1.16.16.`
So if you're using lower version of `Lombok`  you will not be able to use it.

Comment: how can this be the accepted answer when the OP says "I cant mark filed @Builder.Default because..." ?

Comment: There was a known issue/bug with this in v1.16.16. Here's the link: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1347. This annotation was removing the default initialization from the field declaration, which broke the no-args constructor if you had it because using it would not initialize the fields anymore.

Comment: Additional info about a potential problem with using Builder.Default: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883931/default-value-in-lombok-how-to-init-default-with-both-constructor-and-builder

Comment: @tomosius And it's still broken. Builder.Default is unusable if any other constructor is needed (e.g. for JSON deserialization).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just have to write code, so here are a couple more ways of doing this.

#### Use @NonNull

```
@Builder
static class MyEntity {

    @NonNull
    private Set<MyEntity> children;

}
```

- all-args constructor is generated.
- `NullPointerException` is thrown from both the builder and the generated constructor, but with a better message.
- developer **must** pass a value to the builder to avoid the exception.

#### Use @NonNull and Generated constructors

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
static class MyEntity {
  @NonNull
  private Set<MyEntity> children;
}
```

- You need to explicitly declare `@AllArgsConstructor` if you use
  `@NoArgsConstructor`.
- A descriptive `NullPointerException` is thrown from the builder and both constructors.
- developer **must** still pass a value to the builder to avoid the exception.

#### When Using `@Singular`

```
@Builder
class MyEntity {

    @Singular
    private Set<OtherEntitiy> children;

    MyEntity(){
        children = new HashSet<>()
    }


    MyEntity(Set<OtherEntity> children){
        this.children = children == null ? new HashSet<> : children;
    }
}
```

- `@Singular` and `@Builder.Default` are not currently compatible.

  - Using both will cause a pre-compile error.
- Initializing in an explicit no-args constructor will bypass the pre-compile error.
- A parameterized constructor is required by the builder.

  - You will need to check for null and set to default value.
- `NullPointerException` is still thrown if the developer passes null to the builder.
- The field is still nullable if the developer explicitly passes `null` through the
  parameterized constructor.

#### Completely Prevent `null`

```
@Data
@Builder
class MyEntity {

    @Singular(ignoreNullCollections = true)
    private Set<OtherEntity> children;

    MyEntity(){
        children = new HashSet<>()
    }

    MyEntity(Set<OtherEntity> children){
        setChildren(children)
    }

    void setChildren(Set<OtherEntity> children){
        this.children = children == null ? new HashSet<>() : children;
    }
}
```

- Use `@Singular(ignoreNullCollections = true)` to ignore when developers pass a null reference through the builder.
- Add null check and set to default value in an explicit setter.

  - Use the explicit setter to set the value in any explicit parameterized constructors.
- Compatable with @Data, @Getter, and @Setter
- There aren't any required (final) fields, so the required-args constructor is not generated.

#### Force use of Builder

```
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Builder
static class MyEntity {
  @Singular(ignoreNullCollections = true)
  private Set<MyEntity> children;
}
```

- Same results as the previous example, but with less code.
- Less flexible.

  - May not work for certain libraries that require access to constructors.

**Notes:**

Quietly setting the value when `null` is passed instead of throwing a descriptive runtime exception might be more confusing and/or not appropriate for your use cases. Choose the correct approach for your needs.