# OpenAPI generator add annotation on field level

Tags: java, spring, openapi-generator

I am using openapi generator (5.4.0) with gradle(7.3.3) and SpringBoot (2.6.6).

my OpenApi configuration:

```
  ext.openApiConfigOptions = [
            library                       : "spring-boot",
            dateLibrary                   : "java8",
            delegatePattern               : "true",
            useTags                       : "true",
            openApiNullable               : "false",
            additionalModelTypeAnnotations: "@lombok.Builder @lombok.NoArgsConstructor @lombok.AllArgsConstructor",
            booleanGetterPrefix           : "is"
    ]
```

**My goal is to add the @lombok.Builder.Default annotation over the field.**

From documentation:
[image]

According to this: [link to example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54537046/how-to-generate-swagger-codegen-java-models-as-jpa-entities)
I tried using x-field-extra-annotation: in my spec, but it doesn't work in my case.

In my case it works like this;

- x-extra-annotation:"@lombok.Builder.Default" adds an annotation over
  the getter.
- The; x-setter-extra-annotation:"@lombok.Builder.Default" results in
  adding an annotation to the setter.
- But;
  x-field-extra-annotation has no effect.

Similar unanswered question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72321225/openapi-generatorconfigure-lombok-with-builder-builder-default)

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading the openapi generator to version 6.0.0 solves the problem.

Comment: Looks like openapi generator v6.0 is still in beta and not available to us via Artifactory unfortunately. If it is please let me know, I tried adding it and maven couldn't pull the v6.0 dependency

Comment: @user2441441 It has been released 20 hours ago, see https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/releases/tag/v6.0.0