# Default value initialization dosen work with Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I have this pojo class, which is used as apart of REST request

```
@Data
@Builder
public class ListRequest {
    
    @ApiModelProperty(
            value = "Language, default=en",
            allowableValues = "fr, de, sv, en",
            example = "en"
    )
    private Language language=Language.en;

  
    @Transient
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private String apiVersion = "v4";
}
```

I expect that the value of `language` will be `Language.en` if it is missing from the service request
However it is always `null`.

It is Java 101 to initialize the variable that way, so I guess it is Lombok which made this issue.

Any idea what is the issue here?

EDIT: I use neither the constructor nor the builder in my code, its the spring boot who instantiate the objects.

Comment: Please show us how you use your builder

Comment: If your're only using `ListRequest` in a Spring Controller your a) not using the builder at all and could remove that annotation (there are issues when using the builder with defaults https://stackoverflow.com/q/47883931/995891)  b) spring might actively sets the language property to `null`, e.g. when your client sends json request objects that have `"language": null` in them. What spring should do in your case is `new ListRequest()` then set properties

Answer (score 2):

Please try below. @Builder will create the attribute with null by default

```
@Default
private Language language=Language.en;
```

Answer (score 1):

Property for which no value is specified in the builder call will be `null`. Even if you try to set a default value other than `null` and write it in the target class, it will not work.

To set the default value, describe the builder class with the naming convention of target `class name + Builder` as shown below. The rest is nicely complemented by Lombok.

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Value;

    @Data
    @Builder
    public class ListRequest {
    
        @ApiModelProperty(
                value = "Language, default=en",
                allowableValues = "fr, de, sv, en",
                example = "en"
        )
        private Language language=Language.en;
    
    
        public static class ListRequestBuilder {
            private Language language=Language.en;
        }
        @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
        private String apiVersion = "v4";
    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i managed to fix it, thanks to all the contributors.
Apparently there is an issue when try to init default value in lombok with both constructor and builder [Default value in lombok. How to init default with both constructor and builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883931/default-value-in-lombok-how-to-init-default-with-both-constructor-and-builder)

And unfortunately the annotation `@Default` didnot fix the issue

I removed the `@Builder` from the class and added `@NoArgsConstructor`
, and created a new constructor with the annotation     `@Builder`, and excluded all the field i need to init from that constructor

```
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class ListRequest {
    
        @ApiModelProperty(
                value = "Language, default=en",
                allowableValues = "fr, de, sv, en",
                example = "en"
        )
        private Language language=Language.en;
    
        @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
        private String apiVersion;
    
        @Builder
        public ListRequest(String apiVersion){
           this.apiVersion=apiVersion;
        }

    }
```